# Choosing random function from a list

Tags: python, loops, random

I've defined several variables with the questions, answers and category (Prize amount) for a "who wants to be a millionaire" kind of game. Then I have this function who runs based on those Questions, answers and whatnot. I've tried to use the random function of python through shuffle, choice, choices and haven't had success.

Comment: Instead of having multiple variable like that create a `dictionary`

Comment: `rnd.choice=([questionnaire(question1,answers1,correct1,amount1,cat1)` makes no sense: for one thing, you are overwriting `rnd.choice` by assignment rather than invoking it. For another thing, your `questionaire` function doesn't return anything. In any event, why not provide a [mcve]? It still seems as if you are running code that you haven't told us about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly:** I suggest you to create and keep all the questions within a [dictionary.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

**Secondly:** In `rnd.choice =`  you try to overwrite the function by writing `=` which is used to give value to the thing that comes before the equation mark. Try looking up [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp)

**Lastly:** The function `questionnaire()` doesn't return a value, so you don't wanna use it like `rnd.choice=([questionnaire(question1,answers1,correct1,amount1,cat1), ...`

Answer (score 1):

What you're putting into the list isn't the function, it's the result of having already called the function -- the act of building the list itself calls `questionnaire` three times before you have a chance to pick an element out of it.

Putting each question into an object rather than having sets of unique named variables makes it easier to pick a random question as a unit.  You could use a `dict` for this; I usually use `NamedTuple`.

```
from random import choice
from typing import List, NamedTuple, Tuple


class Question(NamedTuple):
    question: str
    answers: List[str]
    correct: str
    amount: int
    cat: int


questions = [
    Question(
        "QUESTION: What is the biggest currency in Europe?",
        ["A) Crown", "B) Peso", "C) Dolar", "D) Euro"],
        "D", 25, 1
    ),
    Question(
        "QUESTION: What is the biggest mountain in the world?",
        ["A) Everest", "B) Montblanc", "C) Popocatepepl", "D) K2"],
        "A", 25, 2
    ),
    Question(
        "QUESTION: What is the capital of Brasil?",
        ["A) Rio de Janeiro", "B) Brasilia", "C) Sao Paolo", "D) Recife"],
        "B", 25, 3
    ),
]


def questionnaire(q: Question) -> Tuple[int, bool]:
    """Presents the user with the given question.
    Returns winnings and whether to continue the game."""
    print(q.question)
    for answer in q.answers:
        print(answer)
    usr_input_answer = input(
        " What's your answer? "
        "Please select between A, B, C, D or R for Retirement. "
    ).upper()
    if usr_input_answer == q.correct:
        return q.amount, True
    elif usr_input_answer == "R":
        print("Congratulations on retirement!")
    else:
        print("Game over!")
    return 0, False


money = 0
keep_playing = True
while keep_playing:
    winnings, keep_playing = questionnaire(choice(questions))
    money += winnings
```